# Как в Play Framework передать коллекцию из контроллера ?

Tags: java, playframework

Как передать во `view` коллекцию `List<Phone> phones` и отобразить их?

Один элемент передается так:

```
public static Result send() {
    Phone phone = Form.form(Phone.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    phone.save();
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    List<Phone> phones = new Model.Finder(String.class, Phone.class).all();
    phone = phones.get(0);
    return ok(show.render(phone.id, phone.company, phone.model, phone.os));
}
```

и отображается так:

```
@(id: String, company: String, model: String, os: String)
@main("Result") {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>company</td>
            <td>model</td>
            <td>os</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@id</td>
            <td>@company</td>
            <td>@model</td>
            <td>@os</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@(phones: java.util.List[model.Phone])

@main("Result") {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>company</td>
            <td>model</td>
            <td>os</td>  
        </tr>
        @for(phone <- phones) {
            <tr>
                <td>@phone.id</td>
                <td>@phone.company</td>
                <td>@phone.model</td>
                <td>@phone.os</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```